# Solr filter value at specific index of an array field

Tags: solr

I have a field in my schema that looks like:

> geoCoords: [-23.380088, 130.207228]

where first element in the array is latitude and second is longitude. I'm trying to   perform simple queries like, find the record with latitude smaller than x etc.

When we search naively like:

> geoCorrds:[0 TO x]

Solr searches all elements in the array that matches the criteria. How can I specify an index?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query for just latitude or longitude by itself, index them as separate fields (i.e. `geoCoords_latitude` and `geoCoords_longitude`).

If you want to do proper spatial queries, you can use [the Spatial Search support](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/spatial-search.html) in Solr.

This will allow you to query with a bounding box to retrieve values that lie within a geographic interval.